# Importar Excel - Laravel, ¿Cómo enviar variables a parte del archivo Excel a importar?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel, maatwebsite

El código **esta funcionando**, importa el archivo Excel **pero necesito enviar la variable seleccionada del combo del formulario** para que ese dato se repita en todos los registros al insertar, ¿Alguien sabe como se puede hacer?

namespace App\Http\Controllers:

```
public function import_excel(Request $request){
        $file = $request->file('import_file');

        $request->codPeriodo;  <-- COMO PUEDO ENVIAR ESTA VARIABLE A AlumnosAsignadosImport?

        $excel_import = Excel::import(new AlumnosAsignadosImport, $file);
        return compact('excel_import');
 }
```

namespace App\Imports:

```
namespace App\Imports\Tutoria;

    use App\Asignado;
    use App\Models\Tutoria\ProgramacionModel;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
    
    class AlumnosAsignadosImport implements ToModel
    {   
    
        public function model(array $row)
        {   
            if($row[0] > 0 && trim($row[0]) != '' && trim($row[1]) != ''){
                $codDocente = $row[0];
                if(strlen($codDocente) < 8){
                    $codDocente = '0'.$codDocente;
                }
                $valido = ProgramacionModel::verificar_alumno($codDocente, $row[1]);
                if($valido == 'valido'){
                  return new Asignado([
                     'codDocente'   => $codDocente,
                     'codAlumno'        => $row[1]
                  ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la solucion fue muy sencilla.

En el controlador :

```
public function import_excel(Request $request){
        $file = $request->file('import_file');

        $excel_import = Excel::import(new AlumnosAsignadosImport($request->codPeriodo), $file);

        return compact('excel_import');
 }
```

En el archivo Import:

```
private $codPeriodo = null;

public function  __construct($codPeriodo)
{
    $this->codPeriodo = $codPeriodo;
}

public function model(array $row)
{   
if($row[0] > 0 && trim($row[0]) != '' && trim($row[1]) != ''){
        $codDocente = $row[0];
        if(strlen($codDocente) < 8){
            $codDocente = '0'.$codDocente;
        }
        $valido = ProgramacionModel::verificar_alumno($codDocente, $row[1], $this->codPeriodo);
        if($valido == 'valido'){
          return new Asignado([
             'codDocente'   => $codDocente,
             'codAlumno'        => $row[1],
             'codPeriodo' => $this->codPeriodo
          ]);
        }
    }
}
```